# Why does Entity Framework Core load nested child entities when connected to a PostgresSQL DB, but not MySQL?

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql

I recently migrated from a MySQL database to a PostGreSQL database in my .NET 7 API application, and I've noticed some really odd behavior now that I've migrated. The application is an Event Registration system, where we sell Badges to Attendees via Sales. I'm looking to merge an external dataset from EventBrite into our dataset.

The strangest thing I've noticed is that, even though I haven't changed ANY of the underlying entities after the migration, I'm seeing calls to the database take significantly longer.

I believe the issue lies within how my Child Entities are set up, as they're circular. I'm searching for an Attendee by their Email Address, and I need to look at all of their Sales, SaleItems, and Badges, and I've noticed that when I make the EF Core call below, it can take up to 10 seconds to return.

```
var attendees = _context.Attendee
                        .Where(_ => _.EmailAddress == email)
                        .Include(_ => _.Badges)
                        .Include(_ => _.Sales)
                           .ThenInclude(_ => _.SaleItems)
                        .Include(_ => _.Sales)
                           .ThenInclude(_ => _.SalePayments)
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

My class definitions look like this...

**Attendee.cs**

```
public class Attendee : EntityBase
{
    public Attendee()
    {
        this.Badges = new HashSet<AttendeeBadge>();
        this.Sales = new HashSet<Sale>();
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AttendeeBadge> Badges { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
}
```

**AttendeeBadge.cs**

```
public class AttendeeBadge : EntityBase
{
    public AttendeeBadge ()
    {
        SaleItems = new HashSet<SaleItem>();
    }

    public int AttendeeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AttendeeId")]
    public Attendee Attendee { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SaleItem> SaleItems { get; set; }
}
```

**SaleItem.cs**

```
public class SaleItem : EntityBase
{
    public SaleItem() { }

    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SaleId")]
    public Sale Sale { get; set; }

    public int AttendeeBadgeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AttendeeBadgeId")]
    public AttendeeBadge AttendeeBadge { get; set; }
}
```

**Sale.cs**

```
public class Sale : EntityBase
{
    public Sale()
    {
        SaleItems = new HashSet<SaleItem>();
    }

    public int AttendeeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AttendeeId")]
    public Attendee Attendee { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SaleItem> SaleItems { get; set; }
}
```

Is there some sort of nesting that happens automatically with the `NpgsqlDbContext` versus the MySql connector? When I had the MySQL connection in use, I would see the query above result in 1 Attendee, with 9 Badges, with an empty SaleItem collection. However, now that I'm on PostGreSQL, I'll see an Attendee with 9 Badges, each with it's own collection of SaleItems, each with it's own Sale, that has it's own Attendee, which has it's list of 9 Badges... And I'm just at a loss.

Comment: I cannot think of anything specific to either MySQL or PostgreSQL with EF that might explain a change in behaviour.  A couple of things to check/eliminate: Have lazy loaded proxies been enabled? The next thing to check would be the lifetime scope of the DbContext. The only reasons references you don't eager might be populated is if either they are lazy loaded, or the DbContext happens to already be tracking them from earlier queries or from living too long. Also Async calls should be awaited if attendees expects to be a collection of Attendee entities.

Comment: Lazy Loaded Proxies have not been enabled. I DID turn them on just to see if I had something wrong there, but when that didn't get me alleviation, I disabled it / reverted the change set. 

The tracking might be the issue, I wonder if throwing .AsNoTracking on it might solve my problem... 

On the awaited async call, yeah I missed that when I was removing all the superfluous information haha. Thanks for the callout though!

Comment: Yes, `AsNoTracking` can help as this both prevents read entities from being added to the tracking cache, but also EF reading/associating other tracked entity references.  Normally for update operations you want to be dealing with tracked instances. For read operations you typically want to use `AsNoTracking` or better, Projection. Neither will inspect/use/append the tracking cache.

Comment: There certainly isn't supposed to be any behavioral difference in loading related entities (Include) between MySQL and PostgreSQL, and nothing in the above model seems strange (or circular). I'd advise simply looking at the SQL logs for both cases and comparing them.